# Opening a new view in the same Shiny, R application

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny application that does some ML calculations and I would like to have two windows: one is the main where you chose your classification objects, and in another window you enter a name of a new class or scroll through a list of names to be able to select them.

How can I have the same server application associated with two views, which are linkable?

It could also be a pop up window for all I care.

Comment: Not sure if you can do two separate windows, but would `tabsetPanel` work? You can separate your views in different tabs.

Comment: Thanks! It was a good idea to solve it using tabsetPanels! :-)